# Converting from one array to another array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I've have this piece of code in C# which convert from one array to another:

```
IWebElement[] elements = Self.FindChildren()
Step[] steps = new Step[elements.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
{
   steps[i] = new Step(elements[i]);
}
```

How can I write it in a shorter way (using linq or lambda expression) ? 
Thanks 
      Omer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Linq` approach

```
IWebElement[] elements = Self.FindChildren();
Step[] steps = elements.Select(x => new Step(x)).ToArray();
```

---

faster but without `Linq`

```
IWebElement[] elements = Self.FindChildren()
Step[] steps = new Step[elements.Length];
Array.Copy(elements, steps, elements.Length);
```